# Make scroll responsive to size of column in flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll

I have a screen with  a column in flutter which is basically a form. At first i had trouble with the fact that the pop-up keyboard reduced the visible space and thus had an overflow. Fixed that adding the SingleChildScrollView and setting a container as a parent with an specific height (based on devicequery size).

Unfortunately, when I test the rotated screen, i get the same problem. Is there a way to set the height of the container which controls the SingleChildScrollView so that it adjusts to the total size occupied by the column widgets?

[image]

Comment: add your code to your question.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: just use listview instead of column

Comment: you can use listview or singlechildscrollview. I suggest you to add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add Listview instead of Colum Widget.

Answer (score 0):

in your scaffold
set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false or add it

```dart
resizeToAvoidBottomInset:false
```